# Is the film line up of The Avengers taken from the comics?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers

In the two recent films *The Avengers/Avengers Assemble* and *Avengers: Age of Ultron*, we see the following people make up the The Avengers team:

- Iron Man
- Thor
- Captain America
- Hulk
- Black Widow
- Hawkeye

From the little I know of the comic book history, I am aware that the line-up has changed frequently over the years. My question is, was the line-up seen in the films specifically created for them, or did this Avengers team ever appear in the comics?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In The Ultimates (The Ultimate universe version of The Avengers, written by Mark Millar and first released in March 2002), the original team consists of;

- Tony Stark (Iron Man)
- Steve Rogers (Captain America)
- Thor Odinson (Thor)
- Bruce Banner (The Hulk)
- Clint Barton (Hawkeye)
- Natasha Romanoff (Black Widow)

but also Hank and Janet Pym (Giant Man and The Wasp) and Pietro and Wanda Maximoff (Quicksilver and Scarlet Witch).

So although the line up seen in *The Avengers/Avengers Assemble* and *Avengers: Age of Ultron* isn't an exact match for this one (and you may not wish to categorize the Ultimates as the Avengers anyway), we can see that the team seen in *The Avengers/Avengers Assemble* and *Avengers: Age of Ultron* is a subset of a team from the comics.

Comment: While they may not be called the Avengers, it's pretty obvious that a lot of the MCU story is being pulled from the Ultimate versions of the characters, so this makes perfect sense :)

Comment: @MichaelEdenfield Yeah - I fully believe that Ant Man and the Wasp would have been in *The Avengers/Avengers Assemble* if not for the lengthy production issues that *Ant Man* faced.

Comment: Bonus: Ultimates Nick Fury's appearance was based on Sam Jackson.

Comment: @DrRDizzle When was this released? If you could add this information to the answer, that would be great :-)

Comment: @maguirenumber6 March 2002, just added to answer.

Comment: Came here to add this exact answer, but you beat me to it.

Comment: @DrRDizzle Have there been problems with making the film?

Comment: @maguirenumber6 It's been in production since 2006, with original director Edgar Wright dropping out just weeks before shooting was set to being, and Marvel then having to scramble to find a new director.

Comment: @DrRDizzle Ah yes, I remember hearing about that now.